# Angular 5 - HTTP Client - converting resp.body to Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I am trying to get my JSON response from the `HttpClient` service into an array so that I can loop through using `*ngFor` in my html. I've tried using "this" to loop through but `*ngFor` will not accept it. Below is the code for my service.ts component and the main component.ts.

I just need some way to convert an array from "resp.body" into an exportable Array to be used for string interpolation in the html. Any help would be much appreciated!

**races.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Race, RacesService} from './races.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'dh-races',
  templateUrl: './races.component.html',
  providers: [ RacesService ],
  styleUrls: ['./races.component.scss']
})
export class RacesComponent {
  error: any;
  headers: string[];
  race: Race;
  raceM: any[];

  constructor(private racesService: RacesService) {
    var raceM = [];
    var raceArray = [];
    this.racesService.getRaceResponse()
      .subscribe(resp => {
        raceArray.push(resp.body);
        for (let obj of raceArray) {
          for (let i in obj) {
            raceM.push({
              "ID": obj[i].id + ",",
              "Date": obj[i].activityStartDate,
              "RaceName": obj[i].assetName,
              "Website": obj[i].website
            })
          }
          console.log(raceM);
          return raceM;
        }
      });

  }
```

**races.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class RacesService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  getRace() {
    return this.httpClient.get(activeApiURL).pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  getRaceResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Race>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Race>(
      activeApiURL, {
        observe: 'response'
      });
  }
```

Comment: Even if I delete all of that code; I am still left with (resp.body) which is still the problem. Need to convert that to some kind of exportable array. Yes you're right, but that code is/was there for testing purposes in attempts to break free of the constructor.

Comment: You don't need to "export" anything just assign it to a property. `this.items = response.body;`. End of story. Right now you have like 14 lines of pure bugs, each obscuring the others, and none do anything you want. Note return value from subscribe callback is discarded by Rx

Comment: Even when I do that; *ngFor will not loop through my items. I can console log it and its there, but when it comes to the string interpolation, your suggestion flat out does not work. Thanks for the help on cleaning up my code though. Still the problem stands.

Comment: What is the shape of items?

Comment: According to console.log it is something like --- [Array(10)] --- 0: Array(10) --- 0: {key: value, key:value} 1: {key: value, key: value}

Comment: It's an array so *ngFor will work, you're probably just using the wrong property names in the loop. Use the json pipe to just output the whole item for each item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue, you need to create an interface that matches the data you get from the server, I will call this interface `IRace`.

Then in the component I will create a variable named `races`, I will assign the returned value from the server response i.e. `resp.body` to the `races` variable.

I'd change the service to look like this:

```
export interface IRace {
   // Your response from server object's properties here like so:

   id: Number;
   assetName: string;
   ...
}

export class RacesService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  getRace() {
    return this.httpClient.get(activeApiURL).pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  getRaceResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Array<Race>>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<Race>>(
      activeApiURL, {
        observe: 'response'
      });
  }
}
```

Finally, I'd change the race component to this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Race, RacesService, IRace } from './races.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'dh-races',
  templateUrl: './races.component.html',
  providers: [ RacesService ],
  styleUrls: ['./races.component.scss']
})
export class RacesComponent {
  error: any;
  headers: string[];
  races: IRace[];

  constructor(private racesService: RacesService) {
    this.racesService.getRaceResponse()
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.races = resp.body;
      });
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Fixed it completely! Changing the observable to an Array with the interface and then exporting it; shows how much I was missing lol. Thank you again!